# How to define a type for a function (arguments and return type) with a predefined type?

Tags: python, python-typing

I want to define a function signature (arguments and return type) based on a predefined type.

Let's say I have this type:

```py
safeSyntaxReadType = Callable[[tk.Tk, Notebook, str], Optional[dict]]
```

which means `safeSyntaxReadType` is a function that receives 3 arguments (from types as listed above), and it can return a `dict` or may not return anything.

Now let's say I use a function `safeReadJsonFile` whose signature is:

```py
def safeReadJsonFile(root = None, notebook = None, path = ''):
```

I want to assign the type `safeSyntaxReadType` to the function `safeReadJsonFile` in the signature, maybe something like:

```py
def safeReadJsonFile:safeSyntaxReadType(root = None, notebook = None, path = ''):
```

But this syntax doesn't work. What is the right syntax for such type assigning?

I can do it this way:

```py
def safeReadJsonFile(root:tk.Tk = None, notebook:Notebook = None, path:str = '') -> Optional[dict]:
```

but I want to avoid that.

After reading a lot (all the [typing docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), and some of [PEP544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/)), I found that there is no such syntax for easily assigning a type to a whole function at the definition (the closest is `@typing.overload` and it's not exactly what we need here).

But as a possible workaround I implemented a decorator function which can help with easily assigning a type:

```py
def func_type(function_type):
    def decorator(function):
        def typed_function(*args, **kwargs):
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        typed_function: function_type  # type assign
        return typed_function
    return decorator
```

The usage is:

```py
greet_person_type = Callable[[str, int], str]

def greet_person(name, age):
    return "Hello, " + name + " !\nYou're " + str(age) + " years old!"

greet_person = func_type(greet_person_type)(greet_person)
greet_person(10, 10) # WHALA! typeerror as expected in `name`: Expected type 'str', got 'int' instead
```

Now, I need help: for some reason, the typechecker (pycharm) doesn't hint the typing if use decorated syntax which supposed to be equilavent:

```py
@func_type(greet_person_type)
def greet_person(name, age):
    return "Hello, " + name + " !\nYou're " + str(age) + " years old!"

greet_person(10, 10)  # no type error. why?
```

I think the decorated style does not work because decoration does not change the original function `greet_person` so the typing from the returned decorated function doesn't affect when inting the original `greet_person` function.

How can I make the decorated solution work?

Comment: I don't think you can do that hen defining a function. You can use your new type as a hint if you were passing a function around though, for example as an argument to another function. Also, is `dict or None` correct? I've always done `Optional[dict]`, but maybe `or` a newer syntax?

Comment: I'm not an expert in python typing.. but in typescript this is how you would assign a type for a function, and for the `dict or None` thing, this works for me in pycharm so for me it is fine

Comment: for the `dict or None` thing, after rechecking I found out this is work if you define it in the function signature, but if you use it inside `Callable` for example it will return Any... so  `Optional[dict]` is probably the correct syntax

Comment: @EliavLouski You can use Mypy package for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply assign the function to a *new* name representing the specific callable type.

```py
Greetable = Callable[[str, int], str]

def any_greet_person(name, age):
    ...

typed_greet_person: Greetable = any_greet_person

reveal_type(any_greet_person)
reveal_type(typed_greet_person)
```

Keep in mind that the object defined as `any_greet_person` *is* of a specific type, which you cannot simply erase after creating it.

---

In order to *create* the callable with a specific type, one can copy it from a template object (the abstract types `Callable` and `Protocol` do not work with `Type[C]`). This can be done with a decorator:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Callable

C = TypeVar('C', bound=Callable)  # parameterize over all callables

def copy_signature(template: C) -> Callable[[C], C]:
    """Decorator to copy the static signature between functions"""
    def apply_signature(target: C) -> C:
        # copy runtime inspectable metadata as well
        target.__annotations__ = template.__annotations__
        return target
    return apply_signature
```

This also encodes that only functions compatible with the copied signature are valid targets.

```py
# signature template
def greetable(name: str, age: int) -> str: ...

@copy_signature(greetable)
def any_greet_person(name, age): ...

@copy_signature(greetable)  # error: Argument 1 has incompatible type ...
def not_greet_person(age, bar): ...

print(any_greet_person.__annotations__)  # {'name': <class 'str'>, 'age': <class 'int'>, 'return': <class 'str'>}
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(any_greet_person) # note: Revealed type is 'def (name: builtins.str, age: builtins.int) -> builtins.str'
```

Comment: @EliavLouski Which of the two approaches? What PyCharm version?

Comment: PyCharm 2020.3.2 (Community Edition) , with the decorator approach.
print(any_greet_person.__annotations__) does print the right types at runtime but no static typing hints [see](![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/47307889/103703680-a79f3780-4fb0-11eb-8c9c-73b2af63ea99.png
)

Comment: @EliavLouski Sorry, it seems that PyCharms builtin type checker is not as exhaustive as e.g. MyPy. PyCharm "correctly" knows that the type of the function is the bare definition with the decorator applied – it does not seem to figure out yet that this affects the signature. You might want to use a different type checker for verification (as said, MyPy works) or open a ticket with IntelliJ.

Comment: after installing Mypy plugin for Pycharm and installing mypy for current interpreter makes pycharm report mypy error! please edit your answer to include this @MisterMiyagi then i will accept this answer!

Comment: Jetbrains is very responsive to issues on their issue tracker. They'd probably fix this all quick like if it were posted there (if not already fixed).

Comment: @DustinWyatt - uh.. I'm a big fan of the jetbrains products, but pycharm has multiple unsolved issues on type hinting regressions and bugs in youtrack. Many of them 1-3 year old. They do a good job maintaining the tracker, but hoping for a quick **fix** is wishful thinking in my experience.

Comment: I can however report that pycharm 2022.2 EAP correctly understands the decorator of the answer :D

Comment: Yes, it depends on the bug. I've had issues solved in days, but others lasting years.

This is the way software goes.