# How to annotate the type of arguments forwarded to another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

Let's say we have a trivial function that calls `open()` but with a fixed argument:

```py
def open_for_writing(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['mode'] = 'w'
    return open(*args, **kwargs)
```

If I now try to call `open_for_writing(some_fake_arg = 123)`, no type checker (e.g. mypy) can tell that this is an incorrect invocation: it's missing the required `file` argument, and is adding another argument that isn't part of the `open` signature.

How can I tell the type checker that `*args` and `**kwargs` must be a subset of the `open` parameter spec? I realise Python 3.10 has the new `ParamSpec` type, but it doesn't seem to apply here because you can't get the `ParamSpec` of a concrete function like `open`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a type for a function (arguments and return type) with a predefined type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65182608/how-to-define-a-type-for-a-function-arguments-and-return-type-with-a-predefine)

Comment: Do you actually need a subset? Your example would accept the same arguments as `open`, albeit silently ignoring one admittedly.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi kind of. The main takeaway I get from that thread is that I can assign to `target.__annotations__`, which I didn't realise. Using a decorator isn't the only way to do that.

Comment: Copying the `__annotations__` is just for runtime inspection. The important part is the annotation of the decorator itself, which copies the *static* type information between function.

Comment: "because you can't get the ParamSpec of a concrete function" - this is such a shame. Was quite disappointing to find out that the new parameter typehinting feature is nowhere near typescript's `ReturnType` and `Parameters` :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think out of the box this is not possible. However, you could write a decorator that takes the function that contains the arguments you want to get checked for (open in your case) as an input and returns the decorated function, i.e. open_for_writing in your case. This of course only works with python 3.10 or using typing_extensions as it makes use of ParamSpec

```py
from typing import TypeVar, ParamSpec, Callable, Optional

T = TypeVar('T')
P = ParamSpec('P')


def take_annotation_from(this: Callable[P, Optional[T]]) -> Callable[[Callable], Callable[P, Optional[T]]]:
    def decorator(real_function: Callable) -> Callable[P, Optional[T]]:
        def new_function(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> Optional[T]:
            return real_function(*args, **kwargs)

        return new_function
    return decorator

@take_annotation_from(open)
def open_for_writing(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['mode'] = 'w'
    return open(*args, **kwargs)


open_for_writing(some_fake_arg=123)
open_for_writing(file='')
```

As shown [here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=0.931&python=3.10&gist=31e2a933dbca2c5ed712c79812a339fd), mypy complains now about getting an unknown argument.

Comment: Since you just copy the entire signature, there is no need to separate its signature. Parameterizing over the entire callable should do the same and be easier. See the proposed duplicate how to do that.

Comment: Why do you define another nested function "new_function" instead of returning directly "real_function" ?

Answer (score 1):

@SimonHawe's answer is correct. However, it could be simplified and modified a little bit to avoid `--strict` rants.

1. Use `Any` for the target function's `*args`, `**kwargs` and return type. They will be overwritten by our decorator anyway.
2. With `cast()`, the target function can just be returned as-is, hence no `wraps()` is needed.

(playground links: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=21dddd86f06aab3cca71be47577ff8ed&flags=strict), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBAxmA28CmMAuBLMA7AzgOgEMAjGKdCABzBFSgGEDFjkBYAKFEilQE8L0sAczKVqtAIJYeAGlgEcqWQAUCIAhADKFFLIAqfJADVV7drqgBeKPu3GQACgDkuxwEp2Sy1BVrN2mE5KbqZsACZIwLBgFDwA%2BjjoglgEqACuIEixnBD2sdSJAgBc9IzwzEgA2kp6ALquUAC0AHwlTETIFRUMbR14fbKSPDU1st1l7ZXV1sOF7FDzUOGR4XBqqNT2qKqCSKjFY%2BUVfXgDUnWNLQcTVbWzbAsPUBlpIFhyCvZXHVO6I9zbu3c9wWcwWz3SbxW1BS1BCAGJGg0kciUai0eiMZisdjMVA4SEAAJwGLxRLJF6ZbL2aJILBApZQGlYLLUWIAdxA6AwQnsACptjhioNZLzeQBrNkCoVSerNKCDO4I%2BYAP1VavVGuVj21Ot18wRMU5ggAFrQdRYWkgQOAQMUAERMlkgdmc7mCO1kHBQCCqMVIUJQeSMgBuVvgYAIoVkRFStCwYBEFGQEFpWww2E9UAo4GD6HCoVB8wlAoqjggYHCjhqXkcbMchaeuwhjO0WD5ApF4slIEEOHqeu1Bp4RtNuotUCtNuKACUm69uAZM6ksGL42ysCF2I7gKyOVyBIJ7DhIJSCH7YtsLABGABMAGZ%2BwO8d6%2BDwoAAyLPDxKj8eT2FsNuu6uge9jAOgyAWI4bhPrBCIQK%2BH5fiOtDjuBWBIPCiI4jhuF4fhKJ4iEDLAGBYBgMUCggNGqjFAIihQLyNEAF7FEQ5HwLKLQAHLYEgdwPNm9FkWANHUVARAEMxQIPISxJxAkSQpOklLgDkwD0hEUDAC6BAUNoDj8j2grylInbFsZ0o8Fxpk8AJYJzm8pFGb25ndr2QIhDpHJ6QZTjhhkECOLIAAsN4sV4uggKkSCyAAjqkAAeXh3ngV4hf28GIZ%2Bho-qhlrWgB3lqPpVr2CFd6yI46AUDgqRBY%2BsFPllMRIblJr5ROhUgFhBF9f1A1IkRbDsNkC78EIiZiCGYYRlGUAADJclajCEmAoYgOGkbsAyh7BsUS2oCt8AVFe5xyvR9nzMcDbsAS62zdtYRaXtB3LWoJ03udLRUVdUA3SNbD3RtW0Fs9kSvVAVE2bxGF-QDO0vfY%2B2Le9jCnbIX1QAAPlDqAgDZ9E43jIDE7D-ENgjQPyaSSkUlkan2IImkQ7ppWGVKtluZzgw2Qq7BKlAmpqk1ou6kOKFji0dqCGzBkeugXo%2BiAfoBkGD2bXN0axlA8aJsmqYpJgbyK1mOZ5v6lN9CEGShowsS8NoTP2FeriNWLcEvq1OXfh1lgtPR7C20g9uO0gzs3m7Htiy1b4%2B5L45UUHSB2-ADsGM7jg7mAbju9Hjyx21vu-jxfHsEAA))

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Any, cast, ParamSpec, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
P = ParamSpec('P')

def copy_signature_from(_origin: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[[Callable[..., Any]], Callable[P, T]]:
    def decorator(target: Callable[..., Any]) -> Callable[P, T]:
        return cast(Callable[P, T], target)
    
    return decorator
```

Example usage:

```py
def f(foo: str, bar: int, *, baz: bool) -> None:
    print(foo, bar, baz)

@copy_signature_from(f)
def f_wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
```

```py
class Parent:
  def __init__(self, foo: str, bar: int, *, baz: bool) -> None:
    ...

class Child(Parent):
  @copy_signature_from(Parent.__init__)
  def __init__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
    ...
```

However, there is one small caveat with Pyright; it will emits an error if the origin function is `@overload`-ed. I think this is a bug and [have reported it](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/7221). It is fixed in 1.1.351.

```py
from typing import overload, Literal

@overload
def g(v: Literal[1]) -> int:
    ...
    
@overload
def g(v: Literal[2]) -> str:
    ...

def g(v: Literal[1, 2]) -> int | str:
    ...

@copy_signature_from(g)
def g_wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
    # mypy    => fine
    # pyright => error: "g_wrapper" is marked as overload, but no implementation is provided
    ...
```

#### IDE support

As of writing (February 2024), this doesn't quite work in PyCharm, but VSCode/Pylance will have good parameter autocompletions:

[image: (foo: str, bar: int, *, baz: bool) -> None]