# How to type hint kwargs when they are passed as is to another function?

Tags: python, python-typing

Suppose I have a fully type hinted method with only keyword arguments :

```
class A:
    def func(a: int, b: str, c: SomeIntricateTypeHint) -> OutputClass:
        ...
```

Now suppose I have a function that takes in variable keyword arguments, and passes them entirely onto that method :

```
def outer_func(n_repeat: int, **kwargs: ???) -> OtherOutputClass:
    a = A()
    for _ in range(n_repeat):
        a.func(**kwargs)
```

In doing so, I have lost the benefits of the type hints for `func`. How do I type hint `kwargs` in `outer_func` such that I recover those benefits ?

For extra detail, in my case, I don't personally define `func`. It's actually a method from a `boto3` client object. As a result I'm looking for a solution that dynamically creates the type hint, rather than having to manually create the TypedDict.

Comment: dict[some types]?

Comment: I don't see how that would dynamically bring forth the variable names and types defined in `func`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type annotations for \*args and \*\*kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031928/type-annotations-for-args-and-kwargs)

Comment: No, as I understand the general rules for typing *args and **kwargs. My question is if there's a way to used an already type hinted function to type hint a **kwargs,

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71253495/how-to-annotate-the-type-of-arguments-forwarded-to-another-function) might be relevant.

Comment: It's very close, but in my case the signatures are not completeley identical, but I can definitely adapt the solution to my case. I must say, that is a very clever use of decorators !

Comment: Beside the point, but why is `self` missing? And why is `outer_func` annotated as returning `OtherOutputClass` when it doesn't return anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, it is `json.loads` wrapper.

My `get_json` accept the bytes and doing the decoding but the json.loads will accept `str | bytes | bytearray` as first argument.

```py
from typing import (
  ParamSpec,
  Callable,
  Generic,
  Concatenate,
  Any,
)

P = ParamSpec("P")

def __get_json_func_creator(
  _: Callable[
    Concatenate[Any, P], 
    Any
  ] = json.loads
):
  def func(data: bytes, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs):
    return json.loads(__get_text(data), *args, **kwargs)
    
  return func;

get_json = __get_json_func_creator()
```

In your case, you're defining `func` in class `A`. Assume that you're missing `self` argument in method declaration and are intended to strip `a` and `b` arguments?

```py
class A:
  def func(
    self, 
    a: int, 
    b: str, 
    c: SomeIntricateTypeHint = None
  ) -> OutputClass: ...

def __wrap_class_a_func(
  _: Callable[
    Concatenate[A, Any, Any, P],
    Any
  ] = A.func
):
  def func(n_repeat: int, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs):
    a = A()
    for num in range(n_repeat):
      a.func(num, str(num), **kwargs)
                
  return func

outer_func = __wrap_class_a_func()
```

Unfortunately, in this case if you want to strip all positional parameter, you will have to define all positional type in `Concatenate`

Comment: Very clever and does the job ! A bit jarring perhaps that some of the logic ends up in the function creator just for the sake of type hinting but I don't think there's a way around that. Thanks for answering my old ass question !