# Is there a way to create type hint - and a type alias - based on a function return value?

Tags: python, type-hinting, pylance

Consider having a function that returns a complex value:

```
def my_fn():
    return (create_this(), create_that(), someotherstuff)
```

Assyming pylance knows what `create_this()` returns as well as what the other values are, it will implicitly tell you `my_fn` returns a `Tuple[Type1, Type2, Type3]`.

Now let's say you have a function that expects to receive an argument that contains whatever this function returned, but you want to still get type hints. You can do this:

```
def process_fn_value(data: Tuple[Type1, Type2, Type3]):
    ...
```

But that's rather verbose, isn't it. It would be better to just write:

```
def process_fn_value(data: ReturnOf[my_fn]):
    ...
```

I have tried the following, hoping to extract the type from a function by making a generic type and then calling `type()` on it. But it doesn't even properly decode the type of the generic value:

```
T = TypeVar('T')
def RetVal(cb: Callable[[Any], T]):
    return type(cb())

def test_fn():
    return "test"

def test_consumer(arg: RetVal[test_fn]):
    return arg
```

Another thing I tried, mostly after looking how `Generic[T]` is implemented:

```
class ReturnValue(Type[T], _root=True):
    def __new__(func, cb: Callable[[], Generic[T]]) -> T:
        return type(cb())

def test_fn():
    return [1,2,3]

def test_consumer(arg: ReturnValue[test_fn]):
    return arg
    
testtype = ReturnValue(test_fn)
```

None of these work.

Is there any such type hint in Python?

<sup>Note: If you think that this is a problem I shouldn't be facing if I wrote the code in such and such way, maybe you're right. But please consider sometimes one cannot change EVERYTHING and yet might be able to create at least partial improvement in the codebase.</sup>

Comment: does multiple dispatch provide another solution to the same problem, albeit one which requires more typing?  I'm assuming `test_consumer` is likely to have quite different code paths for each type, but maybe that's wrong.   More generally, having not run into this I'm curious on the kind of circumstances where you need to call a fn on lots of different types (which aren't reducible to an interface).

Comment: @2e0byo The actual problem is getting type hints for pytest fixtures. These are functions that are evaluated and their return value passed to tests based on names of the test functions' arguments. There isn't really a way for pylance/IDE to know these two things are even related. As a workaround, I thought I could at least simplify it by having arguments annotated like this: `def test_smth(test_file: RetVal[test_file])`. I will google multiple dispatch, but I think what I really need is to know how to build my own type hint construct.

Comment: ah.  Multiple dispatch is more for having multiple *functions* which dispatch on the type of the argument.  (See e.g. the support in [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch)).  I frequently don't typehint my fixtures exactly because of things like this...  Maybe someone knows how to write a `ReturnOf`.

Comment: I recently asked something similar and got pointed towards [this very clever trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71253495/how-to-annotate-the-type-of-arguments-forwarded-to-another-function).